# Access Network Drive/Share over VPN externally

Tags: vpn, network-shares, windows-server-2012-r2

Ive been working on my home network, and I decided that it would be super helpful if I could have a personal VPN hosted at home that I can connect my laptop to, and access my home Domain Controller's network share.

I want to know if this is possible.

I have a domain controller running 2012 R2 and a computer at the office running 10. Is it possible for me to host a VPN via the controller, create a network share, then use that network share over the web by connecting to the VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, and Windows Server provides this functionality (after configuring).

Specifically the feature your looking for is the "RRAS" ([Routing and Remote Access Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_and_Remote_Access_Service)).

Here's an excellent checklist from MS for learning/setting it up (it's for 2008 R2, but most of it still applies):

[Checklist: Installing and Configuring an RRAS VPN Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469733.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I meant 2012 but same thing.